# How can I use an array as a hash value in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

Ok, so here's the entire structure I'm trying to create. I need to create an anonymous array that I can use as a hash value. This works in my program:

```
$result = {
    count, 2,
    elementList, [
        {name => "John Doe", age => 23},
        {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24}
    ]
};
```

I'm trying to create the exact same thing with code like this. This works:

```
my @elements = [
     {name => "John Doe", age => 23},
     {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24}
];

$result = {
    count, 2,
    elementList, @elements
};
```

But this does NOT work:

```
my @elements;
push(@elements, {name => "John Doe", age => 23});
push(@elements, {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24});

$result = {
    count, 2,
    elementList, @elements
};
```

Comment: If the rest of your code breaks with the brackets, the problem is probably over there.  Bring it in the question if you also need help about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you're describing an unusual data structure:  an array with only one element, which is an arrayref of hashrefs.  I'll assume that you really do want that structure for some reason.

```
my @elements = [
    {name => "John Doe", age => 23},
    {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24}
];
```

is equivalent to

```
my @elements = [];
push(@{ $elements[0] }, {name => "John Doe", age => 23});
push(@{ $elements[0] }, {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24});
```

because you want to push the hashrefs onto the arrayref in `$elements[0]`, not the `@elements` array.

But it's unusual to have an array with only one element.  Looking at the additional code you've posted, what you really want is this:

```
my $elementsRef = [];
push(@$elementsRef, {name => "John Doe", age => 23});
push(@$elementsRef, {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24});
```

Or this:

```
my @elements;
push(@elements, {name => "John Doe", age => 23});
push(@elements, {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24});
```

and then use `\@elements` where you currently use `@elements`.

Either one of those will work.  It's up to you to decide which one you prefer.  I'd probably go with the second version.

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning an array reference (the `[]` syntax) to your array.  As a first and only element since you don't specify any others.

You wanted to directly assign a list there, using parentheses `()` instead of the square brackets.

Check out [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for an introduction on the subject.

Comment: The parenthesis are superfluous. You might say @array=() to empty an array, but you never need 'my @array=()'

Comment: @runrig: I was actually talking about the parentheses in the first code excerpt, the one where he describes the structure he wants...  I agree with you about array creation.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong brackets.

You actually need to build a structure like this:

```
my @elements = (
    {name => "John Doe", age => 23},
    {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24}
);
```

To do it in a loop, you will need to modify this code:

```
my @elements;  # same as my @elements = ();
push(@elements, {name => "John Doe", age => 23});
push(@elements, {name => "Jane Doe", age => 24});
```

The reason is that the square brackets build a reference to an array.  A reference to an array is not the same thing as an array.

To make a list of elements to assign to an array, use round brackets `()`.

Answer (score 3):

[] makes a reference to an empty array. You are creating an array with one element. Just say:`my @elements;` to make an empty array.